# How to get attribute value using Selenium - Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

HTML:

```
<div class data="#results">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="testtest" class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-rounded dropdown-toggle">results</a>
```

How do I extract the value of `title` using selenium?

This is what I have tried so far but it gives None.

```
driver.get(url)
toogle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH_HERE")
val = toogle.get_attribute("title")
print(val)
```

Comment: Are you sure there are two _`title`_ attributes?

Comment: Oh no, sorry there's only one title attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the value of the *`title`* attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *class* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data='#results'] > a.btn.btn-white.btn-sm.btn-rounded.dropdown-toggle"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *innerText*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data='#results']/a[text()='results']"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the help :)